# Jquery loop with condition

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm new with jquery and I don't know how to do a loop with a condition. I want to get all the div with the same id (yeah I know id should be unique) and color the border in red. It seems that it's not doing the loop since only the first "#column3" is colored. I want that when #column3 exists, we add class focus.

```
<div id="div2">
  <div id="column1">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
  </div>
  <div id="column2">hello
  </div>
  <div id="column3">3
    <div class="price">600</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <div id="column1">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
  </div>
  <div id="column2">hello
  </div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <div id="column1">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
  </div>
  <div id="column2">hello
  </div>
  <div id="column3">3
    <div class="price">600</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I tried this:

```
 $("#div2 #column3").each(function (index) {
        if ($("#div2 #column3").length) {
            $("#column3").addClass("focus");
        }
    });
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qm89a1cf/2/

Comment: Its a **terriably bad** idea to have multiple elements with same id.

Comment: yeah I know that's why I said it. ^^" But I have to deal with it!

Comment: If you're lucky it might work by using an attribute selector like `div[id=div2] div[id=column3]` but you should just change the HTML.

Comment: you should add classes with the same names

Comment: Its possible this is coming in from a legacy setup, where changing existing code may not be an option. No way of knowing. Sometimes, we got to work with broken HTML until the upper-level dingbats can be convinced of the error of their ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In for each you will get the two parameters first is index and second one element it's self.

You can add this code in your fiddler and it will works.

```
$("#div2 #column3").each(function (index,key) {
        if ($("#div2 #column3").length) 
         {
            $(key).addClass("focus"); //key is elemnt
         }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery .each parameter is a function that accepts several parameters. If you declare the second one, you can access the element. And then give that element the "focus" class.

```js
        $("#div2 #column3").each(function (index, element) {
        element.classList.add("focus");
    });
```

```css
.focus {
border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div2">

<div id="column1">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
</div>
<div id="column2">hello
</div>
<div id="column3">3
    <div class="price">600</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
</div>

</div>
<div id = "div2">
<div id="column1">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
</div>
<div id="column2">hello
</div>
</div>

<div id = "div2">
<div id="column1">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
</div>
<div id="column2">hello
</div>
<div id="column3">3
    <div class="price">600</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>undefined</span>
</div>
</div>
```

```
$("#div2 #column3").each(function (index, element) {
    element.classList.add("focus");
});
```